# PHP Upload Permissions Error

Tags: php, angularjs, file-permissions

I'm setting up a file browser on a php and angular.js server,and the function call to move_uploaded_file fails with a permissions denied error, however I am just SO certain that my permissions are correct, even dangerously open-ended.
 Here's the upload.php file:
http://pastebin.com/uXkeZ4nw
don't worry about that stuff at the bottom, it doesn't do anything and it won't until I've resolved this issue.
The permissions on /var/www/lifecycle/tmp are:
`drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody root 4096 May 13 11:28 tmp`
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It should be noted that this fails on linux, but works fine when I move the server to my Windows machine.

Comment: Is PHP / your web server definitely running under the "nobody" user which is the only one with write access.

Comment: It is not, but the write permissions are set for the world as well as the owner and the group, unless I'm misunderstanding how these permissions bits work?

Comment: Nope, me going crazy not seeing the w's. Anyway, PHP will need read access all the way up the tree to access it, so read for /, /var/, /var/www/, /var/www/lifecycle, so I'd check those next.

Comment: Those all have world read permissions; no dice.

Comment: Next thing to try to to add a trailing / to the end of your UPLOAD_DIR constant as $_FILES name index I don't believe has a leading /.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the UPLOAD_DIR needs a slash at the end, as it is not prepended to $_FILES. s/o to my boy Jon Stirling for the answer.